# Flex and Ruby on Rails start up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

I'm new at Ruby on Rails, but already developed a start project.

Now I figure out that I have to use flash for it, and the best way as I see is Flex.

The problem is that I didn't find no start up guide how to combine these two things. Should I use RubyAMF or WebORB? or both? And will such combination will work fine on Heroku cloud?

For sum up, I'm Looking for some basic info or a short guide for combining RoR and Flex.

Comment: Questions before: Is this a real-time game? Don't you want just to use HTTP protocol? Will you be using RTMP (Audio/Video capture or playback)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a really good book on the subject: ["Flexible Rails"](http://www.manning.com/armstrong/).  It has a ton of good info for the combo.

For me, I have done this with a lot of success.  I use RoR to develop my RESTfull service and I put the Flex app in the `public` folder of the Rails app.  Of course, an Air app can connect to the service the same way.

I then publish the app using Heroku.  The entire end-to-end story is quite solid... assuming, of course, that a Flex-based web app is what you want.  I also like a HTML/Coffeescript/Backbone client that does the same thing... but that is a different story all together :)

Good luck.  This is certainly a fun combo to be developing with.

Comment: Thanks for helpful reply. The book maybe great but has one disadvantage - it has been written for Rails 2 and Flex 3. Most of people use now Rails 3 and Flex 4 I think

Comment: Agreed... It has been a while since I read it and I forgot about it.  BUT, the concepts don't change... just some of the details might have changed.